# Row slicing R dataframe

Tags: r

I don't understand what is happening here. I have a dataframe with 253680 rows.

```
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
> nrow(dataset)
[1] 253680
```

I want to split it into 3 parts: 50%, 25% and 25%. So I take a look at the quartiles:

```
> summary(c(1:nrow(dataset)))
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1   63421  126840  126840  190260  253680
```

Now I'd like access to q2 and q3 to achive the split, but:

```
> quartiles <- as.numeric(summary(c(1:nrow(dataset))))
> quartiles
[1]      1  63421 126841 126841 190260 253680
```

What before were the median and the mean now have a 1 added to them.
Why?

Comment: You are currently only looking the the sequence from 1 - 253680, not the data.frame itself if you print summary(df) you'll get a lot more useful information. Try looking up some very early beginners guides to R and maybe this will start to make more sense.

Comment: do you need something similar to `n <- nrow(iris);split(iris, rep(1:3, c(m <- c(n%/%2, n%/%4), n-sum(m))))` ie three dataframes?

Comment: @Onyambu I'd like to know the values of ```q2``` and ```q3``` so I can split the dataset in 3 by: ```train <- dataset[1:q2, ] validation <- dataset[(q2+1):q3, ]     test <- dataset[(q3+1):nrow(dataset), ] ``` but a couple rows are missing from this split and (I think) it's because q2 and q3  are taken from ```q2 <- quartiles[3]    q3 <- quartiles[5] ```  where ```quartiles```,  defined in my question, has for some reason a +1 added to some of its values. And I'd like to know why that happens

Comment: @IDK check the code I gave you, it splits the data into three. and thats what you need. ie do: `n <- nrow(dataset); l<-split(dataset, rep(1:3, c(m <- c(n%/%2, n%/%4), n-sum(m)))); train <- l[[1]]; validation <- l[[2]]; test <- l[[3]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just a rounding difference since the mean is `.5`.
I cannot reproduce this in my R version though since for me `as.numeric` shows the exact value.

```r
n <- 253680
s <- summary(1:n)
s
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>       1   63421  126841  126841  190260  253680
as.numeric(s)
#> [1]      1.00  63420.75 126840.50 126840.50 190260.25 253680.00
c(s[4], as.numeric(s[4]))
#>     Mean          
#> 126840.5 126840.5
mean(1:n)
#> [1] 126840.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
n <- nrow(dataset);
l <-split(dataset, rep(1:3, c(m <- c(n%/%2, n%/%4), n-sum(m))));
train <- l[[1]];
validation <- l[[2]];
test <- l[[3]];
```